# display a part of image css html

Tags: html, css

I have a image of `width:300px, height:400px;`

My container size is  `width:168px, height:208px;`

I want to display only a part of the image so that it can fill the container.

**like:**
 Suppose top left corner is `0px 0px` bottom right corner is `300px 400px` of the original image. 
I want to display picture from `10px 0px(top-left) to 200px 208px(bottom-right)` such that it fits in the container.

**How to do this in css?**

Answer (score 3):

Use it as background image:

```css
div {
  width: 168px;
  height: 208px;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/300/") no-repeat left -10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Make div `overflow: hidden`

```css
div {
  width: 168px;
  height: 208px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/" />
</div>
```

Comment: I have a gallery of images each 300X400. i have to crop each image such that  image is displayed as: 10px from left to 178px from left(horizontally) and 0px from top to 208px from top (vertically)

Comment: @Abhishek Good for you...

Answer (score 0):

You can set `overflow: hidden` on the container if they are two separate elements. If you're setting the image with the `background-image` property give the `background-size` property a value of `cover` and the `background-position` a value of `top center`

EDIT:

With the new information from your comments in mind, what you should do it order your elements like this:

```
<div class="cut-image">
  <img class="image-to-cut">
</div>
```

Style them like so:

```
.cut-image {
  width: 168px;
  height: 208px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.image-to-cut {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: no i am not using background property. how to do with img tag? and its a gallery of image.. how to apply common css to all?

Comment: Just create a containing div and set it's width and height, then inside it place the `img` tag and set the containing div's `overflow` property to `hidden`.

Comment: i want to crop the image such that image is displayed as: 10px from left to 178px from left(horizontally) and 0px from top to 208px from top (vertically)

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `background: url(placeholder.img) x y no-repeat;`. You need to replace x and y with values (px) from top-left.
Additionally you need to set the div container to `overflow: hidden;`!

```css
.gallery-image {
  background-position: 10px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-image" style="background-image: url("placeholder.img");"></div>
```

Comment: its a gallery of images.. i have to set a common css property to all. how to do without background property?

Comment: Do you have different values for x and y for each image?

Comment: all images are 300X400. i want to crop the image such that image is displayed as: 10px from left to 178px from left(horizontally) and 0px from top to 208px from top (vertically)

Comment: I edited my post above. You can define one class or id with this settings and then change the image at the div container.